# Generate WebService producer from WSDL in Visual Studio 2005

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, web-services, wsdl

I have a WSDL file defining the interface for a web service and I want to implement that service (i.e. producer/server code) using C#, ASP.Net and Visual Studio 2005. Setting up a Web Reference as consumer of a web service is a breeze, but as a producer isn't as obvious.

In the java world there is wsdltojava. Is there something similar to this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes there is. And wait for it, it is called `wsdl.exe`!

The file lives in the Microsoft Windows SDK bin directory (for older version of .NET, the .NET SDK may be in another location).

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. Would be worth adding the '/ServerInterface' option is what I needed.